# Does Ice Cream Sandwich support native screen capture?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, screenshots

I understand that earlier versions of Android do not support a native screen capture feature, unless provided by the specific device, or you have a rooted device, or you have the Android SDK and link via USB. However, I have read that [ICS should support a native screen capture](http://phandroid.com/2011/10/18/ice-cream-sandwich-to-support-native-screen-capture/), but the suggested <kbd>volume down</kbd> + <kbd>power</kbd> combo in that article does not work for me.

I have also tried <kbd>home</kbd> + <kbd>power</kbd>, as seems to work on other devices, but that does not work for me either.

The official [Android Developers site for 4.0.x](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-4.0-highlights.html) states that this should be possible, but doesn't say specifically how...

> **Sharing with screenshots**
>
> Users can now share what's on their screens more easily by taking
>   screenshots. Hardware buttons let them snap a screenshot and store it
>   locally. Afterward, they can view, edit, and share the screen shot in
>   Gallery or a similar app.

I have a generic (DGM T-703) 7 inch tablet with ICS (Version 4.0.3)

Comment: @onik: Ah YES, that's it (I feel a little stupid)! But crucially it's [Power]+[VolDown] (in that order) for a couple of seconds, not [VolDown]+[Power]! If I hit the [VolDown] key first I simply get the volume control on the screen and eventually the device switches off because I've been holding the power button for 5 seconds! If you'd like to put that as an answer, I'll accept, thanks! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The <kbd>Power</kbd>+<kbd>Vol-</kbd> combo isn't instant, you have to hold it for a couple of seconds. And, as you noted, press the <kbd>Power</kbd> button first or you'll get the volume control and power off your phone.

Comment: Wow, this is a useful trick! On my upgraded Nexus S it's tricky to get right though, but it does work.

Comment: How well this works I _think_ is dependent on hardware (or maybe it has been improved in later versions of Android)? As mentioned above, on my tablet this is a little tricky. However, on my (new) Nexus 4 phone I've been able to get a screenshot every time without fail.

Answer (score 2):

After seeing onik's reply I tried the screenshot feature on my phone. On my Nexus S, upgraded to ICS 4.0.4, I have to press the <kbd>Power</kbd>+<kbd>Vol -</kbd> buttons *simultaneously*. Anything else gives me a volume-down or power-off situation.

Comment: I do find that at times the device is more tolerant of a marginal (<1sec) delay between pressing [Power] and [Vol-]. And at other times I can't seem to trigger the screenshot at all!?